# Unable to save data from AngularUI modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I am new to Angular and trying to try few things with AngularUI modal, datepicker and smarttable.

Basically, I want to save the date and count fields in the form of JSON to some file and read it from the same json file for editing purpose. This is my end goal.

So, I have trouble in understanding how to read the modal field values and save it. In the plunker below, I am neither successful in reading the datepicker nor count textbox.

http://plnkr.co/edit/5HtuZy2K9ZiC2lxDKes2?p=preview

I get undefined in the alert box. Why I am not seeing the count value from the textbox.

```
   $scope.ok = function () {
   alert($scope.users.count)
  // $uibModalInstance.close($scope.users);
   };
```

Could someone tell me what wrong am i doing?

Comment: can someone please respond as this is challenging for me to resolve?

Comment: I tried something here but the count is null even after i entered some value                                                                 http://plnkr.co/edit/5HtuZy2K9ZiC2lxDKes2?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

So in the modal, the ng-model of textbox says "user.count". And in controller you are printing "$scope.users". Make sure you have the same variable.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you do not pass user object, you should do:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok(user)">OK</button>
```

Next, use this object in a function:

```
$scope.ok = function (user) {
    console.log(user)
    $uibModalInstance.close($scope.users);
  };
```

Also, make sure do function is in right controller, at the moment I see that they override each other.